# Display dropdown of last 3 months using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, drop-down-menu, struts2

I am trying to display last 3 months of present month (including this total four months) using javascript in drop down

```
function writeMonthOptions() {
    var months = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08",
            "09", "10", "11", "12");
    var today = new Date();
    var date = new Date(today);
    date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1);
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("Month_list");
    var i = today.getMonth();
    var optionNames;
    var optionValues;
    var beanData = '<s:property value="month" />';
    while (i < (today.getMonth() + 4)) {
        optionNames = months[i];
        optionValues = today.getFullYear() + '' + months[i];
        dropDown.options[i++] = new Option(optionNames, optionValues);
        if (beanData) {
            if (beanData == (today.getFullYear() + "" + monthsInd[today
                    .getMonth()])) {
                dropDown.selectedIndex = i - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in simple, show drop down of present month and previous 3 months in the view part.
to back-end it needs to be submitted as [YYYYMM].

if already value present in bean, show it as selected in drop down. [guaranteed that it will be in those 4 months]

Comment: The last two paragraphs are formulated like a homework assignment. Amirite?

Comment: "last 3 months of present month" - Did you mean "last 3 months and [the] present month"?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `(4 times){options.add({shown:t.month, sent:t.year+t.month}); t.add(1 month)}` or are you fighting with a specific part of this?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes  including present month 4 months :)

I am an IT Employee not student ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function returns the `n` last months, including the current one:

```
function getLastMonths(n) {

    var months = new Array();

    var today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var month = today.getMonth() + 1;

    var i = 0;
    do {
        months.push(year + (month > 9 ? "" : "0") + month);
        if(month == 1) {
            month = 12;
            year--;
        } else {
            month--;
        }
        i++;
    } while(i < n);

    return months;

}
```

Call:

```
document.write(getLastMonths(4));
```

Prints:

```
201211,201210,201209,201208
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C2Qfe/)

---

Then, adding those values within a dropdown box is quite easy:

```
function writeMonthOptions() {   

   var optionValues = getLastMonths(4);
   var dropDown = document.getElementById("monthList");

   for(var i=0; i<optionValues.length; i++) {
       var key = optionValues[i].slice(4,6);
       var value = optionValues[i];
       dropDown.options[i] = new Option(value, key);
    }

}
```

Just use:

```
writeMonthOptions();
```

[Full example](http://jsfiddle.net/C2Qfe/2/)

Comment: can you please write how to even add to drop down. I am trying to do with js slice function to get month. But not working :(

Comment: @NitinGurram I edited my answer, see the [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/C2Qfe/2/).